# IPhone crashes on infrastructure code

Tags: ios, iphone, crash

I'm using Crashalytics to figure out crashes on deployment.
I got this crash, the thing is that the entire stack trace has nothing to do with my code.
This happened for a single user out of a few dozens so it is an illusive bug, but I assume it is still my own bug (doesn't get recreated on our devices of course)

Any way I can figure it out?

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2fb71f4b __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39fb26af objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2faabc81 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding
3  UIKit                          0x323bee8d -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1820
4  UIKit                          0x323be699 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 184
5  UIKit                          0x322e4da3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 346
6  QuartzCore                     0x31f6bc6b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
7  QuartzCore                     0x31f6747b CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
8  QuartzCore                     0x31f6730d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
9  QuartzCore                     0x31f66d1f CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 230
10 QuartzCore                     0x31f66b2f CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
11 QuartzCore                     0x31f94033 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 162
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5d8975 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 164
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5d86f3 _pthread_exit + 86
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5d9481 pthread_exit + 28
15 Foundation                     0x304a96af +[NSThread exit] + 10
16 Foundation                     0x30555ca5 __NSThread__main__ + 1092
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5d9c1d _pthread_body + 140
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5d9b8f _pthread_start + 102
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5d7c90 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this? I am facing same issue. It would be great if you could help out.

Comment: Wow... Sorry... It was a year ago. Dont remember if and when I solved it...

Comment: I'm facing exactly same issue - have no idea what to fix...

Answer (score 0):

If that were my stack trace, I would be suspicious about item #2, where it looks like the system is trying to convert a string to a different encoding. `NSInvalidArgumentException` is pretty self-explanatory. Maybe you are passing a string encoding that isn't a valid Foundation string encoding type? It seems to be while a `UITableView` is scrolling or being displayed.

Comment: hmmm... well, I don't prevent the users from entering text in their own language... maybe this is the problem. Do you know any sources for do's and don'ts regarding these issues?

Comment: As long as you're sticking to Foundation string types and using UIKit for input, languages should work. Unless the input is coming from somewhere else, like server-side? For instance, if a user has entered some double-byte text on a web page, and you're displaying it as ASCII on the device. I still don't see why that would cause an invalid argument exception though.

Comment: It's guessing, not an answer